# Delete large number of branches from remote

Tags: git, git-push, remote-branch

I have a Git remote that has 1000 branches, and I want to delete all the branches whose name does *not* start with `foo_`. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Short answer

If your remote is called "origin", run

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:strip=3)' refs/remotes/origin/* | \
  grep -v '^foo_\|^HEAD$' | \
  xargs git push --delete origin
```

## More details

### Prefer `git for-each-ref` over `git branch`

The other answers suggest piping the output of `git branch` to `grep` or `awk`. However, such an approach is brittle: `git branch` is a Porcelain (i.e. high-level) command, whose output may change in a future Git release. A better alternative is to use [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref), a powerful Plumbing (i.e. low-level) command.

### Explanation of the command

(Note: the following assumes that your remote is called "origin".)

Use `git for-each-ref` to list all the remote branches on `origin` in an adequate format:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:strip=3)' refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Pipe the output to

```
grep -v '^foo_\|HEAD$'
```

to discard `HEAD` and all the branches whose name starts with "foo_". Finally, pipe the output to

```
xargs git push --delete origin
```

to delete all the relevant remote branches from `origin` in one fell swoop.

Caveat: Of course, the command above won't be able to delete *current branch of the remote* if the latter doesn't start with "foo_".

Comment: Almost correct, except I said delete all the branches that *don't* start with foo. But I appreciate the use of `for-each-ref`, that looks superior.

Comment: @RamRachum Oops! I should have read your answer more carefully. I'll amend the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why the * you had in your previous answer wasn't automatically expanded by bash before being processed by the git command? (Just curious)

Comment: @RamRachum I'm not sure what you referring to. The `*` I had *was* being expanded by bash before being processed by Git...

Comment: How can the `*` be expanded by Bash, unless I'm inside the `.git` folder? Because there isn't a `refs` folder in the repo root.

Comment: If you take the effort to use a plumbing command to get a "safe" output, you should at least escape the `*` in case someone creates a `refs` folder

Comment: For EL7 users, this won't work with the default git 1.8.3.1. `fatal: unknown refname: format strip=3`. After enabling git 2.18 from SCL, the error doesn't appear anymore, for me at least.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following command in order to remove all branches with PREFIX on remote server.

```
git branch -r | awk -F/ '/\/PREFIX/{print $2}' | xargs -I {} git push origin :{}
```

You may want to do a dry-run first to see if it is the branches that you want to remove:

```
git branch -r | awk -F/ '/\/PREFIX/{print $2}'
```

If you like a simpler approach, for instance delete 3 or 4 branches:

```
git push origin --delete <branch1> <branch2> <branch3>
```

For your further information:

1 - List all your remote branches:

```
 $ git branch -r
```

2 - Filter the branches by some regular expression. In this case we are interested in deleting any branch with the 'feature-' prefix:

```
 $ git branch -r | awk -F/ '/\/feature-/{print $2}'
```

3 - Pipe the last command to git push to delete them:

```
$ git branch -r | awk -F/ '/\/feature-/{print $2}' | xargs -I {} git push origin :{}
```

4 - Remove any local reference to those branches:

```
$ git remote prune origin
```

Comment: This looks like it could take a long time with 1000 git pushes over the network. Wouldn't it be better to populate a variable with branch names first and do one push?

Comment: That could be an improvement possibility. Btw, Did you try this way already?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to list all remote branches not starting with foo_ using:

```
git branch -l -r|grep -v 'origin/foo_'
```

If that looks OK to delete you can use xargs to redirect the output to a `git push origin --delete` command:

```
git branch -l -r|grep -v 'origin/foo_'|xargs git push origin --delete
```

Comment: Doesn't your `xargs git` command need an extra `-r` flag to delete remote branches?

Comment: Will this work without fetching from the remote first?

Comment: @WimMostmans It would, I updated it to use `git push origin --delete` instead, as per the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Deleting-Remote-Branches).